# changing the value of a column using an indicator and a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have

```
        household      person     mode     time     
           1             1         car      8:00 
           1             2         car      9:00       
           1             3         bus      7:00        
           1             4         bus      7:30       
           1             4         walk     8:30
           1             5         car      10:00
           2             1         car      9:00
           2             2         bus      11:00
```

I need to change the time of bus and walk by time of car if their time is at most 1 hour behind than car. If more than one car is available their time will be the closest car.

output

```
        household      person     mode     time     
           1             1         car      8:00 
           1             2         car      9:00       
           1             3         bus      8:00        
           1             4         bus      8:00       
           1             5         walk     9:00
           1             6         car      10:00
           2             1         car      9:00
           2             2         bus      11:00
```

In the first family person 3 and 4 have closer time to first driver.

Comment: So do the `person` and `household` numbers not matter in this?

Comment: data grouped by household, so in each household I want to compare

Comment: But the `person` doesn't matter?

Comment: no, it is not matter,

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` + `lubridate` option

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(household) %>%
    mutate(time = if_else(
        mode %in% c("bus", "walk") &
        hm(time) < hm(time)[mode == "car"] &
        as.numeric(hm(time) - hm(time)[mode == "car"]) / 3600 <= 1,
        time[mode == "car"], time)) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 6 x 4
#  household person mode  time
#      <int>  <int> <fct> <fct>
#1         1      1 car   8:00
#2         1      2 bus   8:00
#3         1      3 bus   8:00
#4         1      4 walk  8:30
#5         2      1 car   9:00
#6         2      2 bus   11:00
```

Explanation: This is quite a literal translation of your condition. We `group_by` households, then modify the time if the mode is "bus" or "walk" and their times are 1 hour or less behind the time of "car".

Comment: my time format is '%H:%M:%S', can be the error because of that?

Comment: @shere Well, yes that makes a difference. Try substituting `hms` for `hm`.

Comment: still error: Error: `true` must be length 6 (length of `condition`) or one, not 4
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: The problem is I have more than 1 person with mode car in each household, could you plz fix it?

Comment: @shere Can you please update your post to include representative sample data in a reproducible format, eg using `dput`.

Comment: @shere hmm. So in the case of multiple "car" entries how do you decide which entry to use in the comparison? Can you please take a step back and edit your post to include critical details in the main post. Take your time and give a clear and unambiguous problem statement including the rules to get from your sample input to sample output. It’s tedious to piece together what you actually want to do through back-and-forth comments.

Comment: I actually mentioned that closest driver is chosen

Comment: @shere Fix your post! So far through comments we had to find out that (1) you want to group by "household", (2) "person" is irrelevant, (3) your time format is actually HH:MM:SS and not HH:MM as in your sample data, and (4) you have multiple "car" entries per "household". All of this belongs in your main post! Do you see the problem?